# Entity Creation Via Select Box

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, angularjs

When an option a user desires is not present in a select box, how can I make it possible for the user to create a new option via the select box itself, via-a-vis quickbook, harvest, etc?

I thought of including a "create" option within the select box and when it is chosen to display an adjacent text box. On submission, the new "option" would be submitted within a separate param hash. The backend API would process the new option request first within a transaction. While I believe this approach would work, I feel as if there has to be a better way. Thoughts/insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I usually do this:

Next to the select box I add a button "Add new". When clicked, this button would open a modal dialog (e.g. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog) with a form for creating a new entry.

When user fills in the dialog form and clicks "Save", after successful response from the server I would close the dialog and update the select box options, either by  pulling the list from the server again, or by just appending the new item to the previously fetched list.

At the end of the process I would than pre-select the newly created item because that's what user intended to select in the first place.

---

Other solution would be to use something like select2 plugin and directive (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) where it's tagging support enables you to create new tags in-place.